# How to show pop-up on button click in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I have the following page in jsp .

[image]

The code of the page is as following :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Language content=en-us>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<style TYPE="text/css">
    <!-- BODY               { font-family:arial,helvetica; margin-left:5; margin-top:0}
            A                   { color:#FF5500; text-decoration:underline}
            A:hover,A:active    { color:#0055FF; text-decoration:underline}
        -->
</style>
<Script Language="JavaScript">
<!--
function inStrGrp(src,reg)
{
    var regex=new RegExp("[" + reg + "]","i");
    return regex.test(src);
}

function check()
{   
    var uname=document.scan.elements[0].value
    var bError=false

    if (uname.length==0)
    {
        window.alert("Name is required.\n")
        return false
    }
    if (uname.indexOf("\\")>=0)
        bError=true

    if (inStrGrp(uname,'/.:*?"<>| '))
        bError=true
    
    if (bError)
    {
        window.alert('User name can not contain the following characters:\n \\/. :*?"<>|\n')
        return false
    }
    else 
        return true  
}
-->
</Script>

<title>Enroll New Fingerprint.</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="document.scan.name.focus();">
<center>
<table border="0" width="800">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><u><b>Online Demonstration</b></u></p>
      <div align="center">
      <table border="1" width="100%" height="260">
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" align="center" rowspan="2">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p><font color="#0055FF">Enroll</font></p>
              <p><a href="logon.asp">Logon</a></p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td width="80%" height="30">
              <b><i>Enroll Finger</i></b>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td width="80%">
      <p>Thanks for your registration. You can enroll two fingers for the name you registered.</p>
    
      <form name="scan" method="POST" action="enroll.jsp" onsubmit="return check()">
        <p>Please input your name: <input type="text" name="name" size="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
        <p>If you want to enroll 2 fingers, please check the box. <input type="checkbox" name="chk2Finger" value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="   Enroll   " name="btnEnroll"></p>
      </form>
        
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3">
      <p align="center"><small>Copyright © 2004 Futronic
      Technology Company Limited. All Rights Reserved.</small></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

When I click on Enroill button I want to show a pop-up like as following with an image source tag .

[image]

How can I do this on Jsp ? Any advice is of great help .

Answer (score 1):

Here is  code snippet using bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
    <title>Online Demonstration</title>  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
   
 <div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">Online Demonstration</div>
    <form name="scan" method="POST" action="enroll.asp">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <p>Thanks for your registration. You can enroll two fingers for the name you registered.</p>
     <div class="row">
      
      <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="col-md-5">Please input your name:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                               <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="UserName"/>
                            </div>
      </div>
     
     </div>
    
     <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="col-md-5">If you want to enroll 2 fingers, please check the box.</label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="chk2Finger" value="2">
         
         </div>
      
                      </div>
      
      </div>
       <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
   </form>  
  </div>
 </div>
 
<!-- Modal code goes here-->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="container">
  <div class=row>
  <img src="" class="img-thumbnail col-lg-2">
   </div>
   </div>
   
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal --> 
  

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function inStrGrp(src,reg){
  var regex=new RegExp("[" + reg + "]","i");
  return regex.test(src);
 }

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userName = document.getElementById('UserName').value;
     var bError=false

   if (userName.length==0)
   {
    window.alert("Name is required.\n")
    return false
   }
    if (userName.indexOf("\\")>=0)
    bError=true

   if (inStrGrp(userName,'/.:*?"<>| '))
    bError=true

   if (bError)
   {
    window.alert('User name can not contain the following characters:\n \\/. :*?"<>|\n')
    return false
   }
   else 
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    return true  
  

  });
 });
 
 </script>
 
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With pure its not possible to show pop up and show image on that pop up.You can do it with jquery UI dialog .
And it will be great if you use bootstrap framework which have modal where you can insert anything you want.

Comment: Help me to do this using bootstrap